# ¿Cómo puedo acceder al valor de una de las columnas de un WebGrid en Razor?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, razor

Tengo este WebGrid al cual le paso los datos a partir de una lista "LlistaIdiomesCand"

```
@{
     WebGrid GridTIdiomes = new WebGrid(Model.LlistaIdiomesCand);
}
<h2>IDIOMES ADICIONALS</h2>
@if (Model.LlistaIdiomesCand != null)
{
@GridTIdiomes.GetHtml(
htmlAttributes: new { id = "taulaIdiomes", @class = "taula table  table-bordered" },
tableStyle: "table",
alternatingRowStyle: "alt",
selectedRowStyle: "select",
columns: GridTIdiomes.Columns(
GridTIdiomes.Column("Nom_Idioma_Ad", "IDIOMA"),
GridTIdiomes.Column("Text_Nivell", "NIVELL"),
GridTIdiomes.Column(format:  @<text> <a href="#" class="btnEsborrar" data-id="@item.Id"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span></a></text>)))
```

¿Cómo puedo acceder al valor de una de las dos columnas cada vez que carga una linea para trabajar con el? Es que tengo un WebGrid (no es el de el ejemplo, pero no importa) en el cual en una columna tengo un año y quiero hacer la diferencia con el año actual para encontrar la edad.

Comment: quieres accederlas desde codigo cliente, con javascript ? o es estando aun en el servidor durante el render de la view

Comment: En el servidor, a medida que va generando cada hilera de la tabla (con C# en la view "Razor" vaya)

Comment: los datos de las dos columnas son propiedades del modelo que asignas al WebGrid, en lugar de acceder al datos desde el grid como control podrias hacerlo usando Model.LlistaIdiomesCand, aunque no estoy seguro que es lo que quieres hacer con los datos de las dos columnas, donde necesitas usarlo?

Comment: Tengo una columna (no es el webgrid que he puesto aqui en el ejemplo) en la cual tengo un año, pues con ese año quiero calcular la edad de la persona comparandolo con el año actual.

Comment: edita la pregunta y añade esta nueva explicacion del calculo de la edad al problema asi queda completa y se relaciona tu consulta con la respuesta

Comment: tienes un GridView o es un WebGrid ?

Comment: Tengo un WebGrid

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Podrias usar la técnica que ya estabas utilizando cuando defines el `format`

```
GridTIdiomes.Column("Edad", format: item => DataTime.Now.Year - item.Año)
```

o sino

```
GridTIdiomes.Column(header: "Edad", format: item => DataTime.Now.Year - item.Año)
```

[MVC3: WebGrid Column Format Issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5394791/mvc3-webgrid-column-format-issue)

[ASP.NET MVC3 WebGrid format: parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5122691/asp-net-mvc3-webgrid-format-parameter)

Comment: Me dice que Datatime... y el item no existen en el contexto actual si lo pongo tal cual lo has puesto tu

Comment: edite la respuesta, analiza si los cambios aplican correctamente